# Same coordinates printing in pd dataframe although iterating trough rows, using pd and geopy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, geopy

I am writing a program to retrieve long and lat coordinates from hospital names using geopy nominatim. Nominatim is powerful at finding coordinates although city and country are not always listed. The script works fine but the coordinates printed do not correspond to each row, the same coordinates are printing in the dataframe.

First, I read the excel file containing hospital names using pd and converted it to a df. I also defined the geolocator.

```
    from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
    import pandas as pd
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='geoapp')
    data = "Hospital.xlsx"
    data = pd.read_excel(data)
    data.dropna(inplace = False)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then, I defined each row to be the next iteration in the df using next(), and I used a for loop to get the coordinates for each row. I also set the coordinates to equal NA if the hospital name is TBD. The code works with no errors, but it is printing the same coordinates in each row.

```
row = next(df.iterrows())[1]

for row in df:

    location = geolocator.geocode(row, addressdetails=True)
    df['lon'] = location.raw['lon']
    df['lat'] = location.raw['lat']

    if row == 'TBD':
        df['lon'] = 'NA'
        df['lat'] = 'NA'

    else:
        df.fillna('N/A', inplace=True)
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Coordinates.xlsx")
        df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Summary')
        workbook = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets['Summary']
        worksheet.set_zoom(90)
        worksheet.set_column('A:Z', 20)
        writer.save()
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cop3x.png)

I am reiterating through each row so not sure why I am getting the same coordinates for each row as shown in the screenshot. Any help or tips are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: `df['lon'] = scalar_value` sets the **entire** column to that single value. Because you loop, the result is the entire column being set to the last value you looped over.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense. Any idea on how I can fix that? Thank you

Comment: `df.apply()` is a typical solution. See https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.20.0/#usage-with-pandas